# Generating 5x5 matrix with random numbers in each box

Tags: random, matrix

I need to generate in PHP a matrix(5x5) in which, every box must contain different random number between 1 and 1000. I have tried like that but it generates me only 1 random number in every single box:

```
$random = rand(1, 1000);
echo '<table border="1" style="width:200px">';
    for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) {      
        echo "<tr>";
            for ($j=0; $j < 5; $j++) { 
                echo "<td>";                
                    echo $random;
                echo "</td>";
                }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: do you need it in a specific language? if so, which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put random inside your loop:

```
....

for ($j=0; $j < 5; $j++) { 
                echo "<td>";                
                    echo  rand(1, 1000);
                echo "</td>";
```

Comment: Thank you very much... I thought i have tried all ways of my code but obviously i missed the right one!

Answer (score 0):

You are only assigning your variable a random value once.

You can do 1 of the following:

You need to either make a separate function that you call at

```
echo "<td>";
   echo CALL_FUNCTION_HERE
echo "</td>";
```

or

Create an array and fill it with random numbers.

```
echo "<td>";
   echo $myArray[j];
echo "</td>";
```

or

Move your declaration:

```
echo "<td>";
   $random = rand(1, 1000);
   echo $random;
echo "</td>";
```